# Cannot Move CSS Loader Container

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a problem regarding the positioning of my container.

Keeping the styles whilst removing the `position: absolute;` on the `.dot` seems to be proving rather tricky and with each attempt the `dot`s are going all over the place!

To clarify, I'm looking at being able to move the entire loader

```css
.sampleContainer {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 60px;
  background: white;
}
.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left:100px;
}
.dot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #888;
  position: absolute;
}
.dot_1 {
  animation: animateDot1 1.5s linear infinite;
  left: 12px;
  /**background: #e579b8;**/
}
.dot_2 {
  animation: animateDot2 1.5s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  left: 24px;
}
.dot_3 {
  animation: animateDot3 1.5s linear infinite;
  left: 12px;
}
.dot_4 {
  animation: animateDot4 1.5s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  left: 24px;
}
@keyframes animateDot1 {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-12px); }
  25% { transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-12px); }
  75% { transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-12px); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(-12px); }
}
@keyframes animateDot2 {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-12px); }
  25% { transform: rotate(-180deg) translateX(-12px); }
  75% { transform: rotate(-180deg) translateX(-12px); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg) translateX(-12px); }
}
@keyframes animateDot3 {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(12px); }
  25% { transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(12px); }
  75% { transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(12px); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(12px); }
}
@keyframes animateDot4 {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(12px); }
  25% { transform: rotate(-180deg) translateX(12px); }
  75% { transform: rotate(-180deg) translateX(12px); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg) translateX(12px); }
}
```

```html
<div class="sampleContainer">
  <div class="loader">
    <span class="dot dot_1"></span>
    <span class="dot dot_2"></span>
    <span class="dot dot_3"></span>
    <span class="dot dot_4"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you wanting to move it?

Comment: @HunterTurner Well on my page I was trying to float it, set margin or whatnot so it doesn't show other anything else. See this quick [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xy3wctqw/)

Comment: Did you try to add position:relative to loader class?

Comment: @MoisheySchwartz yes, my attempts seem to have a domino effect causing more problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set `position:relative` to parent, otherwise it will be out of the DOM flow.

As for my tests you don't need the `.loader` CSS

```css
.sampleContainer {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 60px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
}

.dot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #888;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 15px 8px
}
.dot_1 {
  animation: animateDot1 1.5s linear infinite;
  left: 12px;
  /**background: #e579b8;**/
}
.dot_2 {
  animation: animateDot2 1.5s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  left: 24px;
}
.dot_3 {
  animation: animateDot3 1.5s linear infinite;
  left: 12px;
}
.dot_4 {
  animation: animateDot4 1.5s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  left: 24px;
}
@keyframes animateDot1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-12px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-12px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-12px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(-12px);
  }
}
@keyframes animateDot2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-12px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(-180deg) translateX(-12px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(-180deg) translateX(-12px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg) translateX(-12px);
  }
}
@keyframes animateDot3 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(12px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(12px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(12px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(12px);
  }
}
@keyframes animateDot4 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(12px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(-180deg) translateX(12px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(-180deg) translateX(12px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg) translateX(12px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left">Deleting 'Folder Name' folder</div>
<div class="sampleContainer">
  <div class="loader">
    <span class="dot dot_1"></span>
    <span class="dot dot_2"></span>
    <span class="dot dot_3"></span>
    <span class="dot dot_4"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you notice on your version, the dots are no longer spaced out evenly, one of the problems I have experienced.